# How can I optimize repetitive IF-Else code?

Tags: php, optimization

I have the following code block which I used in many files with slight changes in condition and the output varies accordingly. How can I optimize that?

```
$url = 'changeAble';
if ($this->someModel->someMethod()) {
    $msg = 'Changeable message';
    $msg_type = SUCCESS;
}else{
    $msg = 'An error occured.';
    $msg_type = ERROR;
}
redirectWithFlashData($msg, $msg_type, url);
```

**Update:**
I've learned to optimize my code. Here it is:

```
$url = 'changeAble';
if($this->someModel->someMethod()) 
    redirectWithFlashData('Changeable message', SUCCESS, $url);
redirectWithFlashData('An error occured.', ERROR, $url);
```

Comment: Can you create a separate util file & add a new function which accepts the "arguments"  & put your if else inside it. Based on the "argument" or whichever condition, you can change the output and return it. Import this util file in all your other files where this function is called. I'm not familiar with php syntax but hopefully the general concept helps you so you follow the "DRY" principle.

Comment: I can. But this logic is used in many classes and each class has a different message. That's the issue

Comment: If the code works and you're just asking for someone to review it and come with suggestions, please post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: then pass that message as an argument as well. Is 'someMethod' always the same method or that changes as per the class as well ? @Yasin

Comment: @user2821242 changes as per the class

Comment: ok then create a util function which accepts the callback function(someMethod in your case)  as an argument along with the changeable message. You can then invoke someMethod inside your util function. If that is not possible then pass the output of the 'someMethod' as an argument to this util function.

Comment: ```
function utilFunc(callback, message) {
      if(callback()) // do something
      else //do some other thing 
}

utilFunc(someMethod, 'hello') // use this in your other files.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that receives a callback predicate:

```
function redirectWithFlashDataIfNeeded($predicate, $url) {
    if ($predicate()) {
        $msg = 'Changeable message';
        $msg_type = SUCCESS;
    } else {
        $msg = 'An error occured.';
        $msg_type = ERROR;
    }

    redirectWithFlashData($msg, $msg_type, $url);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
$url = 'changeAble';
redirectWithFlashDataIfNeeded(function() {
    return $this->someModel->someMethod();
}, $url);
```

Or just pass the boolean result directly:

```
function redirectWithFlashDataIfNeeded($flag, $url) {
    if ($flag) {
        $msg = 'Changeable message';
        $msg_type = SUCCESS;
    } else {
        $msg = 'An error occured.';
        $msg_type = ERROR;
    }

    redirectWithFlashData($msg, $msg_type, $url);
}

...

$url = 'changeAble';
redirectWithFlashDataIfNeeded($this->someModel->someMethod(), $url);
```

Comment: Yeah. But the problem is the message which changes for each class.

Comment: Then pass it as parameter as well. Or wrap this functionality in a class and use inheritance/traits to provide different messages...